# MSTest Doesn't Pull Down Different Versions of Newtonsoft.JSON.dll

Tags: .net, unit-testing, json.net, mstest

We use MSTest to run automated tests against our solution.  Some of the projects in the solution are targeted for .NET 3.5 and are referencing Newtonsoft.JSON.dll version 4.0.8.  Other projects are target for .NET 4.0 and are referencing a signed version of Newtonsoft.JSON.dll version 4.5.7.  When MSTest runs against all the tests, the tests using the later version of Newtonsoft fail with:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).

But if I run just the tests running the later version of the DLL, they execute successfully.  I looked into the Test/OUT directory and confirmed that for failed runs, only the earlier version of the Newtonsoft DLL is there, and for successful runs only the later version of the DLL is there.

So, how can I either 1) Force MSTest to copy over the proper binaries each time, or 2) Force MSTest to bring in different versions of the same binary side by side?

TIA.

Comment: The problem is that your test deploy different versions of the same dll in Test/Out directory so the one is just overriden by another... hmmm... how do you start your tests? Are they just UninTests running at the end of a nightly build?

Comment: I'm running it through a home grown test utility that scans folders and subfolders looking for test DLLs, and then each DLL is added to the command line argument passed to MSTest with the "/testcontainer:" flag.

Comment: To my knowledge the only way to cause MSTest deploy binaries “each time” is to have several test runs. That means you will need a MSTest call for DLLs referencing Newtonsoft.JSON.dll version 4.0.8 and second MSTest call for DLLs referencing Newtonsoft.JSON.dll version 4.5.7. But I suppose it will be not easy with your way to start tests...

Comment: Yes, I think I came to that realization myself.  I wasn't willing to admit defeat yet though.  Thanks for pondering this with me.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm sorry I could not help... I first thought you could solve it using test categories: use different categories for tests referencing different versions of Newtonsoft.JSON.dll and let your test tool generate two mstest calls using identical /testcontainer but different categories. But then I realized that it would not affect loading of the DLLs... I did not try it, but I'm pretty sure it would not help in your case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to my knowledge there isn't a solution using MSTest from the command line.  MSTest copies all of the /TestContainers into the /Out directory, along with all of the dependencies.  In my case it found the reference to the older version of Newtonsoft.JSON.dll first, and copied that over.  Then when it resolved the dependencies for the other Newtonsoft.JSON.dll, it didn't copy it over.

My solution is to change the utility to run an instance of MSTEST per assembly, instead of running it for all the assemblies at once.